# How to call mycart product names in sidebar

Tags: magento, product

I'm using magento 1.6.1.0. I included new sidebar in my cart page where it'll show product title, total amount & proceed to checkout button as one by one. I included total amount by calling `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>` and proceed to checkout button by calling `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>`

But i don't know how to call Product name.

Anyone know how to call my cart products name which are currently added in basket? Please share your idea to do this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to your cart object via Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart').
Calling Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItems() will get you your current cart item collection that you can iterate through to get product names as well as other details.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItems(); 
foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getName();
    }
```